# Set up OpenNLP: Text Detection using the Vision java API

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, intellij-idea, opennlp

> Set up OpenNLP
>   Download Tokenizer data and save it to this directory.

```
wget http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/en-token.bin
```

This is what Google asks me at [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/text#set-up-opennlp)

I got no clue what OpenNLP is so I [google](https://opennlp.apache.org/building.html) it.

This is what Apache says on their Setup OpenNLP page:

> If you have an IDE installed such as NetBeans or Eclipse installed, it
>   will make your development easier. However, **follow on for the brave**.

### I got Intellij NetBeans, how do I set it up?

When building with maven in Intellij and attempting to run this sample, this is the error that I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: en-token.bin (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

When I try to continue with Google doc I fail in this line:

```
java -cp target/vision-text-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.google.cloud.vision.samples.text.TextApp data/
```

With an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.cloud.vision.samples.text.TextApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you need from OpenNLP is that Tokeniser .bin file - this is just a binary file that the library uses to tokeise text (e.g. split sentences into words). It would appear like there is nothing else you need from that library - If you look in the google vision pom file(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/text/pom.xml) you will see they have a dependency on the OpenNLP JAR, so here you are just grabbing the pre-trained resource for that library.

Assuming you have cloned that GitHub repo, and have successfuly run the maven command they mention:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

Then that downloaded file (`en-token.bin`) should be copied to the root of the project directory (the same location as the pom.xml and where you are running the java command).

If the setup is like that then it should work ok.

Comment: When executing clean I get:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project text: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8

Comment: sounds like a java version conflict - assume java 8 is required, what do you have locally?

Comment: yeah that was java problem in mvn